# static dbHandle null after connection using MVC and Singleton

Tags: php, pdo

This is my Singleton class connection:

```
class Conexao { 

        private static $instance;

        protected function __construct(){ }
        private function __clone() { }
        private function __wakeup() { }

        public static function conectar(){                                                              
            //Connection Variables
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            //String connection PDO
            $connString = "mysql:host=" . $servername . ";dbname=sistema_login;charset=utf8mb4";                

            try {
                $instance = new PDO($connString, $username, $password);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex) {
                echo("Não foi possível abrir o banco de dados.");
            }

        }

         public static function getInstance()
        {
            return static::$instance;
        }

}
```

And this is how I am connecting and trying to use the connection handle in another class:

...

```
Conexao::conectar();
$dbInstance = Conexao::getInstance();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `veiculos_tipo`';   
$stmt = $dbInstance->prepare($query);
```

...

Problem is that I am getting that error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   C:\wamp64\www\marmitaria\Model\DAO\EntregadorDAO.php on line 9

that refers to this code: `$stmt = $dbInstance->prepare($query);`
I don´t understand why it´s happening since code is not going to catch block when connection is trying to be stabilished.

Comment: This error message means that static::$instance is null. And why is it null? Where it gets populated? In essence. You have an error message. Why not to read it and trace the problem back in your code?

Comment: -> `self::$instance = new PDO(...`

Comment: Currently you're assigning the PDO instance to the local variable $instance. Assign it to the static class member self::$instance instead. ...or static::$instance

Comment: VolkerK: Perfect. self::$instance = new PDO(... solved the problem. Please make this a awnser so I can vote up for you.

Comment: Aside: what's the point in catching the exception? Then `static::$instance` will also just be `null` and will result in the same error down the line. **Don't catch exceptions unless you have an alternative plan what to do instead.**

Answer (score 0):

As VolkerK said

```
self::$instance
```

fixed the problem!